Not able to send post request with Content Type "x-www-form-urlencoded" with Clojure
I'm basically trying to do the following cURL command in Clojure:
curl --location '<auth-url>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=<client-ID>' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=-<client-secret>'
--data-urlencode 'audience=<audience>'

I've tried the following in Clojure, using [org.httpkit.client :as http]:
(http/post auth-url {:form-params {:grant_type    "client_credentials"
                                   :client_id     client-id
                                   :client_secret client-secret
                                   :audience      audience}
                     :headers     {"Content-Type" "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}})

I'm finding that the cURL command works, both in Terminal and Postman, but the Clojure code returns a 403 Forbidden. I've double, triple checked that the url and all the param values are correct.
I've also tried encoding and appending the form params to the URL as query params using the following functions:
(defn make-query-string [m]
  (->> (for [[k v] m]
         (str (codec/url-encode k) "=" (codec/url-encode v)))
       (interpose "&")
       (apply str)))

(defn build-url [url-base query-map]
  (str url-base "?" (make-query-string query-map)))

but I get the same 403 Forbidden response.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in the Clojure code, if anyone has any pointers. Thank you!

Have you tried adding :debug true to your options of the post and checked, if there is more to this error?

if it were me and I felt stumped, then I'd set up a local echo server and post to it both from curl and clojure/http-kit and inspect what's getting sent to find the difference. My guess would be either some kind of double-encoding, or extra/missing headers.

Maybe try specifying form-params as strings instead of keys and no need for specifying the headers:
(let [opts {:form-params {"grant_type" "client_credentials"
                          "client_id" client-id
                          "client_secret" client-secret
                          "audience" audience}}]
  @(http/post auth-url opts))

